# GWT and Javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt

Unable to call javamethod from javascript in a GWT java class.

Please find the code snippet from below.

```
package abc;

public class jsclass extends Composite {

public native boolean getOnlineSchedlueResult() /*-{

    function listener(event) {

    //alert("getOnlineScheduleResult called 2 Outside");
     var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
     if(data.FinderSuccess == true){
        parent.onlineMoveNavigation = this.@abc.jsclass::onlineMoveNavigation()();
     }
  }

  if (parent.addEventListener){
        //alert("parent getOnlineScheduleResult called 3");
        parent.addEventListener("message", listener, false);
        //alert("getOnlineScheduleResult called 3A");
        parent.postMessage("test", "*");
 } else {
        //alert("getOnlineScheduleResult called 4");
        parent.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
        parent.postMessage("test", "*");
 }

}-*/;

    public void onlineMoveNavigation(){
        GWT.log("onlineMoveNavigation called");
        presenter.moveNavigationNext();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why post commented code?

Comment: A JSNI comment block begins with the exact token /*-{ and ends with the exact token }-*/. It is not a commented code.

Comment: What is the purpose of `parent.onlineMoveNavigation`? Is it supposed to store a function or the result of `this.@abc.jsclass::onlineMoveNavigation()()`? I'd wager it's the latter case (since `onlineMoveNavigation` returns `void`). In which case you want to drop the second pair of parentheses: `parent.onlineMoveNavigation = this.@abc.jsclass::onlineMoveNavigation();` to actually store a reference to the `onlineMoveNavigation` method in `parent.onlineMoveNavigation`.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword won't evaluate to your `jsclass` instance when `listener` is called by the browser.
You have to *bind* your `jsclass` instance to a variable that you can reference from your `listener` function/closure.

```
var self = this;

function listener() {
  //alert("getOnlineScheduleResult called 2 Outside");
  var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if(data.FinderSuccess == true){
     parent.onlineMoveNavigation = self.@abc.jsclass::onlineMoveNavigation()();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thomas. Now it is invoking method onlineMoveNavigation. Appreciate your assistance.